# In the case of closures, why use two parentheses?

Tags: python, function, closures

I am studying Python closure with a book. I made a function. That function is reducing 1. I don't understand why to use two parentheses? When I use the assigned variable `c`, the return value is function.

```
n=int(input('enter c: '))
def countdown(n):


    def count():
        global n
        r=n
        n -= 1
        return r

    return count

c=countdown(n)

for i in range(n):
    print(c(),end=' ') # I don't understand why use c() not c.
```

Comment: What does `countdown` ***return?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is a function within the `countdown` function which is `count`, and also, when you return the `count` method you don't add parenthesis, that's why you need to.

It will return:

```
<function countdown.<locals>.count at 0x00000007237F31E0>
```

If you print `c`.

`countdown(...)` returns a function, that which also needs to be called.